# Overriding Admin -> Sales -> Orders -> Edit -> Products page in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I am currently working on a refund extension for both Alipay and 99Bill, and this is all done in the admin panel (user does not see this extension).

I am interesting in adding a refund button to the `Order -> Edit -> Products` page, which would allow greater granularity in refund (per-product refund), since the refund button on the order list refunds the entire amount.

The page in question is displayed below:

[image]

I spent some time searching for the `Controller` and `View` for this page (looking at the URL above, it sales sale/order/update), but navigating to `/admin/sale/order` and then the `update()` function, it did not seem relevant to what I am changing.

I am quite interested in overriding the red button which removes the product from the orders list - I would add the refund logic there.

Could someone point me to the Model/View/Controller for this Orders -> Edit -> Products page?

Comment: What you need is the `getForm()` method in the controller and the corresponding `order_form.tpl` template.

Comment: @shadyyx shadyyx, since it seems you're like the only OpenCart developer that is ever on StackOverflow (and most of my questions are unanswered on the OC forums) and answers questions, mind if I add you on Skype or something?

Comment: I'm not the only one, there are few others, but from what I have observed there are only two really *taking care* of `opencart` tagged questions here in long terms (others just come and go). Unfortunately, I would mind. Too many reasons which I even do not need to explain :-) Thus, keep asking here if you have problems/questions (don't take it personally nor wrong).

Comment: @shadyyx No hard feelings =)

Comment: @shadyyx I know that when you press the red "remove" button on the `Product` page, it does an AJAX call that POSTs a bunch of information, and resultingly removes the item from the product list. It seems to call `route=checkout/manual`. There's no `checkout` folder in `admin`, but there is one in `catalog`. Do you know what function removes an item in the Products tab? Or if it's even PHP at all.

Comment: Ok. I found that button in `order_form.tpl`, and it's jQuery: `onclick="$('#product-row<?php echo $product_row; ?>').remove(); $('#button-update').trigger('click');"`

Comment: Checking out the POST data when you click the red button, it doesn't actually seem like there is an key related to `quantity`. When you *add* a product, however, in the POST, there *is* a quantity key. Does this mean it's not possible to remove a certain quantity, but you *can* add a certain quantity?

Comment: To your last question - yes, exactly. You can only remove the product with all the quantity from order - you cannot just remove 2 pieces out of 10. To do that, you need to remove the product and then add it again with new quantity... Not that much confusing and nothing a user couldn't handle :-)

Comment: @shadyyx I see. Is it possible for your to tell me what function removes an item in the Products tab? Whether it's a JS function or a PHP function. When you press a button, it calls `route=checkout/manual` and POSTs all the data to that URL, but looking at `catalog/controller/checkout/manual`, I do not see anything relevant to what I need. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: @shadyyx I found the `add()` which is responsible for adding a product (you can change quantity in this one). As I am looking now, there is no `remove()`. That's the function I am looking for.

Comment: `add()` can be accessed via `$this->cart->add(..)`, wanted to add.

Comment: Ah! Found it. It's under `system/library/cart.php`!